# Windows 11 wifi issue

Tags: windows-11, wifi-driver

i tried the windows trouble shooting and got the following diagnose "There might be a problem with the driver for Wi-Fi adapter".
i tried to update the intel wifi adapter but it was already up to date.

hp, DESKTOP-APVE4IR
windows 11, version 21H2

any ideas ?

Comment: Get the HP Driver Update App and update all drivers.  Then get the HP Hardware Diagnostic App and test hardware.

Comment: What Intel WiFi adapter do you have exactly? [Edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I deleted the wifi driver trying to fix the problem so i cannot know now the drivers version